# Different CSS style for JSF messages

Tags: jsf, coding-style, richfaces, message

In JSF, I have included the following line in my xhtml file:

```
<h:panelGroup id="messageHeader">
   <h:messages for="messageHeader" layout="list" errorClass="error"  infoClass="inform"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

The text gets rendered as

```
<ul>
  <li class="error"> Please enter a First Name </li>
  <li class="error"> Please enter a Last Name </li>
</ul>
```

How do I get the CSS style to apply to the `<ul>` tag or some surrounding `<span>` tag?

Here is what I am trying to do.  I want all error messages to appear in a single red box.  I also want all info messages to appear in a single green box.  The example above produces 2 red boxes; one for each `<li>` item.

Comment: A different question may be: how can I get just the error messages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `styleClass` attribute of `<h:messages>`. It will be applied on the parent HTML element.

E.g.

```
<h:messages styleClass="messages" />
```

will end up as

```
<ul class="messages">
    ...
</ul>
```

---

**Update**: you seem to want to show info and error messages in **separate** lists. Use two `<h:messages/>` instead on which you hide the other severity.

```
<h:messages styleClass="errorMessages" infoStyle="hide" />
<h:messages styleClass="infoMessages" errorStyle="hide" />
```

with

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: @BalusC But how do I specify a style for info and a separate style for error messages?

Comment: Just keep using `errorClass` and `infoClass` like you already did. The `styleClass` won't override it. You were asking how to set a `class` on `<ul>`, right?

Comment: @BalusC Yes, I am trying to set the class on `<ul>` but I want a different class based upon the severity of the messages.  I am now realizing that `<h:messages ...>` could return messages with differing severity levels.  Can I just get the messages for a specify severity level?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. JSF 1.x or 2.x?

Answer (score 0):

This could be done by providing h:messages tag for each message type you need to show with appropriate condition. For exapmle for error message type:

```
<h:panelGroup id="errorMessageHeader" class="whatever you need" rendered="#{FacesContext.isValidationFailed()}">
   <h:messages for="errorMessageHeader" layout="list" errorClass="error" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Conditions for other message types you can find by combining methods from

> javax.faces.context.FacesContext

Thanks,
A.K.

Comment: I am going to try this technique, but how do I test FaceContext for info messages?

Comment: @Ryan: this EL example is invalid. The correct example depends on whether you're using JSF 1.x or 2.x and whether you're using JSP or Facelets. But after all, there are simpler ways.

Comment: @BalusC Thank for comment. I haven't checked if it is valid, just wanted to show main point.

Comment: @Ryan in JSF 1.x or 2.x it could be done by comparing max severeties (FacesContext.getMaximumSeverity()) instead, but I suggest using BalusC suggestion, as realy it is much simpler.